# Layout CSS & HTML, Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this layout of pictures. As you can see the first picture of the first line is not in the same line with the first picture of the second line. It's a bit off... How can I fix it? I need them all to be equally aligned. I have attached the whole code. Please help. I tried margin, padding, display but did not get it right.

[image: here is the image pointing to the issue]

```css
body {
  background-image: url('../images/background.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}


.circle-count {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}

.main {
  background-color: #feeeea;
}




/*Gallery*/
.photo-modal {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.photos-container {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.photo-element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 30px 30px 0 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image-fix {
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: inherit;
}

.add-photo {
  background: #f5e0db;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.likes-count {
  position: relative;
    right: -180px;
    top: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 17px;
    background-color:  #e87193;
}



.add-photo input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
.add-photo .fa {
  color: #e8bcb5;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
.add-photo label {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #e86d8f;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

  .photo-info-author {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .photo-author-name {
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }

  .all-photo-likes {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    color: #e87193;
  }
  .all-photo-no-likes{ 
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    color: #bbbbbb;
   }




.second-line-photos{ 
margin-top: 39px; }

.third-line-photos{  
margin-top: 79px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="description" content="Компания TASOMA промо текст"> 
  <meta name="author" content="Soft Group">

  <title>Vikids</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Main style -->
  <link href="assets/css/vikids-css.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400i,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>

<!-- START Main container -->
<main>
  <div class="container-fluid main">
    <section class="row photos-container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="photo-element add-photo">
            <label>
              <input type="file">
              <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <p>Добавить <br/>фотографию</p>
            </label>
            </div>


            <div class="photo-element">
              <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
              <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="photo-element">
              <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
             <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
             <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
              <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
              <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
              <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
               <img class="image-fix" src="./assets/images/gallery/gallery6.png">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
              <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
              <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="photo-element">
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
           

            
        </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
<!-- END Main container -->



<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ae7c834c9a.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I will appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: can't understand your question.

Comment: you are using row without container, correct this first

Comment: @AnkitSingh I attached the picture, pointing to the issue. please check

Comment: @MarMar check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added comments to the snippet below.

Summary is...

1. Use `position: absolute` on your 'like counter'. Add `position: relative` to its container.
2. Remove the `padding` around the image container
3. Change `.add-photo` vertical-align to `top`.
4. Space the photos using `margin` (I've increased the top margin to 60px)

*update as per comment with regards aligning information under the photo*

Given your current layout, you could simply remove the negative left and right margin added to `.row`. You can also remove the `padding-left` on the 'likes' item at the end of the row.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('../images/background.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

.circle-count {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}

.main {
  background-color: #feeeea;
}


/*Gallery*/

.photo-modal {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photos-container {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.photo-element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 60px 30px 0 0;
  /* Increase top margin to space */
  border-radius: 15px;
  /* padding: 15px; Not needed */
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  /* Needed to position number of likes */
}

.image-fix {
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: inherit;
}

.add-photo {
  background: #f5e0db;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* Change from 'bottom' */
}

.likes-count {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: #e87193;
}

.add-photo input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}

.add-photo .fa {
  color: #e8bcb5;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.add-photo label {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #e86d8f;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photo-info-author {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.photo-author-name {
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.all-photo-likes {
  /* padding-left: 15px; */
  padding-top: 8px;
  color: #e87193;
}

.all-photo-no-likes {
  /* padding-left: 15px; */
  padding-top: 8px;
  color: #bbbbbb;
}

.second-line-photos {
  margin-top: 39px;
}

.third-line-photos {
  margin-top: 79px;
}

.photo-element .row {
margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="description" content="Компания TASOMA промо текст">
  <meta name="author" content="Soft Group">

  <title>Vikids</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Main style -->
  <link href="assets/css/vikids-css.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400i,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- START Main container -->
  <main>
    <div class="container-fluid main">
      <section class="row photos-container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="photo-element add-photo">
            <label>
              <input type="file">
              <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <p>Добавить <br/>фотографию</p>
            </label>
          </div>


          <div class="photo-element">
            <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
            <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="photo-element">
            <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
            <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="photo-element">
            <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="photo-element">
            <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
            <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="photo-element">
            <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="photo-element">
            <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="photo-element">
            <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="photo-element">
            <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
            <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="photo-element">
            <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
            <img class="image-fix" src="./assets/images/gallery/gallery6.png">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img class="photo-info-author" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="photo-element">
            <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
            <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="photo-element">
            <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
            <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="photo-element">
            <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="photo-element">
            <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="photo-element">
            <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>




        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </main>
  <!-- END Main container -->



  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ae7c834c9a.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but now as you can see the content under the picture is going out. the heart icons under the images.

Comment: @MarMar I've updated the answer. I think you are finding the layout challenging because you are using a lot of small pixel adjustements to different items, using flex in some places and bootstrap classes in others. You could explore flexbox or grid instead, I think you'd find it simpler in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am going to take your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Close your first `<div class='col-md-12'>` and reopen after closing if you want to break...

```css
body {
  background-image: url('../images/background.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}


.circle-count {
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}

.main {
  background-color: #feeeea;
}




/*Gallery*/
.photo-modal {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.photos-container {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.photo-element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 30px 30px 0 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image-fix {
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: inherit;
}

.add-photo {
  background: #f5e0db;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.likes-count {
  position: relative;
    right: -180px;
    top: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 17px;
    background-color:  #e87193;
}



.add-photo input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
.add-photo .fa {
  color: #e8bcb5;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
.add-photo label {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #e86d8f;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

  .photo-info-author {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .photo-author-name {
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }

  .all-photo-likes {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    color: #e87193;
  }
  .all-photo-no-likes{ 
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    color: #bbbbbb;
   }




.second-line-photos{ 
margin-top: 39px; }

.third-line-photos{  
margin-top: 79px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="description" content="Компания TASOMA промо текст"> 
  <meta name="author" content="Soft Group">

  <title>Vikids</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Main style -->
  <link href="assets/css/vikids-css.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400i,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>

<!-- START Main container -->
<main>
  <div class="container-fluid main">
    <section class="row photos-container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="photo-element add-photo">
            <label>
              <input type="file">
              <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <p>Добавить <br/>фотографию</p>
            </label>
            </div>
  </div><!--add this-->
  <div class="col-md-12"><!--add this too-->

            <div class="photo-element">
              <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
              <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="photo-element">
              <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
             <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
             <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
              <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
              <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
              <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
               <img class="image-fix" src="./assets/images/gallery/gallery6.png">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
              <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
              <span class="likes-count"> 37 </span>
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="photo-element">
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="photo-element">
               <img class="image-fix" src="https://www.babble.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/supercutebaby1-200x200.jpg">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"> 
                  <img class="photo-info-author" src="./assets/images/users/marina-ivanova.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 photo-author-name"> Имя Фамилия 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"> 
                  <i class="all-photo-no-likes fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
           

            
        </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
<!-- END Main container -->



<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ae7c834c9a.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```